# Matrix multiplication error when using mllib

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, matrix-multiplication

I'm using Spark 1.6 with YARN, I have a job which do some calculation using Spark `mllib`, one of which is matrix multiplication, I'm using `CoordinateMatrix` to do it. The code is like this:

```
def coordinateMatrixMultiply(leftMatrix: CoordinateMatrix, rightMatrix: CoordinateMatrix): CoordinateMatrix = {
  val M_ = leftMatrix.entries.map({ case MatrixEntry(i, j, v) => (j, (i, v)) })
  val N_ = rightMatrix.entries.map({ case MatrixEntry(j, k, w) => (j, (k, w)) })
  val productEntries = M_.join(N_)
    .map({ case (_, ((i, v), (k, w))) => ((i, k), (v * w)) })
    .reduceByKey(_ + _)
    .map({ case ((i, k), sum) => MatrixEntry(i, k, sum) })
  new CoordinateMatrix(productEntries)
}
```

But I got an error, which says:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Both matrices must have the same number of rows. A.numRows: 159, B.numRows: 158
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.BlockMatrix.blockMap(BlockMatrix.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.BlockMatrix.add(BlockMatrix.scala:397)
    at com.sankuai.nlpml.kg.syn_sim.SynSim$.process(SynSim.scala:312)
    at com.sankuai.nlpml.kg.syn_sim.SynSim$.main(SynSim.scala:365)
    at com.sankuai.nlpml.kg.syn_sim.SynSim.main(SynSim.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:635)
```

I have submitted the job many times, but not all got this exception. I debugged the code and found that `coordinateMatrixMultiply` method's return value varies, yet the code remain the same. I don't know why and I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing the multiplication yourself, consider converting to `BlockMatrix` and using the provided `multiply` method. After the multiplication, convert back to a `CoordinateMatrix`:

```
def coordinateMatrixMultiply(leftMatrix: CoordinateMatrix, rightMatrix: CoordinateMatrix) =
  leftMatrix.toBlockMatrix().multiply(rightMatrix.toBlockMatrix()).toCoordinateMatrix()
```

Comment: I got this exception:

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The number of columns of A and the number of rows of B must be equal. A.numCols: 159, B.numRows: 51. If you think they should be equal, try setting the dimensions of A and B explicitly while initializing them.

Comment: @Gao That sounds like a problem with your input data. You can only perform a matrix multiplication if the number of columns in matrix A and the number of rows in matrix B are the same. Are you sure the input stays the same the whole time? It could also be that you need to switch the positions of `leftMatrix` and `rightMatrix`, the `multiply` method depends on which matrix is to the left respectively right.

Comment: I'm trying to use Matrix instead of CoordinateMatrix to try it again :)

Comment: the problem is the return value of coordinateMatrixMultiply varies all the time (I'm using numRows() method to count the row, and it's varies), I guess maybe it has some connection with concurrency...

Comment: @Gao If the output varies, then the input should vary as well (easily checked with the numRows/Cold on the inputs). I don't believe the method itself should have any such issues. How are the `leftMatrix` and `rightMatrix` created? It seems this should be the origin of your problems (maybe create a new question with more information about the matrix creation process before the multiplication?).